# How to roll back master page in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I've done some changes in master page in SharePoint Designer. After that I'm trying to roll back to the original of master page.

It's showing error

> Something went wrong

I need to get my original master page .

Answer (score 0):

If you have Versioning enabled on your master page gallery, you can restore it back to the original version.

Answer (score 0):

Error something went wrong is probably due because you didn't check in your masterpage (and approve it) even you'd like to cancel changes.

So first do this, validate totally the masterpage and try to restore a previous version before your changes.

If you cannot do this, create a new site collection, then pick up the masterpage from this site and replace the one you change.